# Checking if pair of values exists in pair of columns?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am attempting to find in Excel whether a unique pair of values exists across two columns in a separate spreadsheet. For example:

Array 1

```
1 - A
2 - B
3 - A
4 - C
```

Array 2

```
1   D
2   E
2   B
3   C
```

I would like the column next to 2, B to return "TRUE", and all other columns to return "FALSE", as 2B exists in Array 2 but none of the other pairds do.

I've tried surfing Stack Overflow for this problem as I felt it would be a very common lookup but surprisingly have had no luck so far. VLookups have given some results but they stop at the first pair. For example let's say we had Array 3:

Array 2

```
1   D
2   E
2   B
4   C
```

Now both 2B and 4C in Array 1 should return trues.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Formula in `C1`:

```
=COUNTIFS(D:D,A1,E:E,B1)>0
```

Comment: I initially thought this wouldn't work, because I didn't think it was checking pair-wise, but it does. That is to say, this **isn't** the same as `=AND(COUNTIF(D:D,A1)>0,COUNTIF(E:E,B1)>0)` which is what I'd assumed.

Answer (score 0):

Array one in Column A

Array two in Column B

Paste this XLookup in Column C1, then drag formula down to C4. The corresponding values that match will be listed next to the values from Column A if they exist in Column B.

```
=XLOOKUP(A1,B$1:B$4,B$1:B$4,"",0,1)
```